# When does a subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}(n, \mathbb Q)$ have a bounded fundamental domain on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, lattices, arithmetic-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Let $G \subset M_{n\times n~}(\mathbb Z)$ be a **finitely generated** subgroup of $\GL(n,\mathbb Q)$ (i.e. $g\in G$ is an invertible matrix with entries in $\mathbb Z$). Then $G$ acts on $\mathbb R^n = \mathbb Z^n \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R$ through $\GL(n,\mathbb Q)$.

Suppose that there is a **rational affine** subspace $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ (by this, I mean that there is a sub-lattice $L \subset \mathbb Z^n$ and $a \in \mathbb Z^n$ such that $V = a + (L \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R)$), and $V$ is invariant under the action of $G$ (i.e. for any $v\in V, g\in G$, we have $g\cdot v \in V$). Moreover, there exists $v \in L$ (in fact, we can take $v=a$) such that
$$G \cdot v = L.$$

**Question**: is there a bounded subset $P \subset V$ such that $$\bigcup_{g \in G}\  g\cdot P = V \quad ? $$

Any suggestion on relevant questions/references is very welcome! Particularly, I don't know which field studies such problems ….

**Edit:**

**Example.** Consider $(0,1)+L:=(\mathbb Z,1) \subset \mathbb Z^2$, and $$G=\{\begin{pmatrix} 1&k\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}.$$ For $v=(0,1)$, we have $G \cdot v =(0,1)+L$. In this case, we can take $P$ to be the interval from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$.

Comment: Usually a fundamental domain is required to satisfy stricter conditions than your $P$.  You only need $P$ bounded?

Comment: Yes, for me "$P$ bounded" is enough. I don't know how to characterize such set in one word in the title, so I coin the name "fundamental domain".

Comment: The hypothesis cannot be satisfied by any subgroup of ${\rm GL}_n({\bf Z})$,
finitely generated or not, because the action of ${\rm GL}_n({\bf Z})$
preserves the subgroups $M {\bf Z}^n$ of ${\bf Z}^n$, so for example
cannot take a nonzero vector $v$ to $2v$, let alone to the zero vector.
Did you mean to require that $G \cdot v$ consist of all *primitive*
integer vectors?

Comment: You are right! I should say "$\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of the elements in $G \cdot v$ is equal to $\mathbb Z^n$"

Comment: Then the answer is negative, you can take for instance the standard linear representation of the permutation group on $n$ symbols.

Comment: @MoisheKohan You are absolutely right! Thank you! I didn't abstract my problem properly. Now I correct my question.

Comment: Notice the result is false in one-dimension $n=1$, since there does not exist a bounded subset $P$ of $\mathbb{R}$ for which the $GL(\mathbb{Z}^1)\approx \{\pm 1\}$ translates cover $\mathbb{R}$. Makes me think the result is even false for $GL(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ acting on standard lattice $\mathbb{Z}^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ...

Comment: If you replace $GL(\mathbb{Z}^n)$ with $GL(\mathbb{Z}^n)$. then there exists a bounded $P$ whose $GL(\mathbb{Q}^n)$ translates cover $V$. [Proof required]

Comment: You still have this $Gv=L$ even after Noam's comment. Even if you mean $<Gv>=L$, I do not think there is any choice of quantifiers for your question for which the answer is nontrivial.

Comment: @JHM Sorry, but I totally confused. Isn't $GL(1,\mathbb Z) = \mathbb Z\backslash\{0\}$? Then in $\dim V=1$, any interval will cover $V$ after translations.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I don't know where the problem is: (1) I define $GL(n, \mathbb Z)$ to be set of $n \times n$ invertible matrices with entries in $\mathbb Z$, and (2) I take the affine subspace so that $G \cdot v = L$ can happen. This question actually originates from the following setting: Consider an abelian variety $X$ and $A$ is an ample line bundle. $L$ is the set of Cartier divisors which are numerically equivalent to $A$. The automorphism group $G$ of the abelian variety will send $A$ to any divisor $B$ if $\phi_A: X \to \hat X$ is an isomorphism. Hence, $G \cdot A = L$.

Comment: $GL(\mathbb{Z}^1)\approx \mathbb{Z}^\times=\{\pm 1\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}^\times$ is multiplicative group of units. If $V$ is *affine* and $G$-invariant, then $G|_V$ is an *affine* representation of $G$ (more complicated). If $V$ is linear subspace, then your question appears to be: "are all lattice vectors at some uniform distance from a *primitive* lattice vector?" I think the answer is No, but I might be wrong. Also this question might be answered in a lemma from Borel/Harish-Chandra "Arithmetic Subgroups of Linear Algebraic Groups". Need verify.

Comment: @JHM Thank you! I see where the confusion comes from - I should say $G \subset GL(n,\mathbb Q)$ is a subgroup such that $G \subset M_{n\times n} (\mathbb Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments, I think the underlying algebraic question is: " if $G=U$ is a unipotent linear algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, then is the arithmetic unipotent subgroup $U(\mathbb{Z})$ cocompact in $U(\mathbb{R})$? "

The answer to the above question is Yes, as well known to students in geometry of numbers, reduction theory of quadratic forms, and arithmetic groups. For example, a proof is contained in Borel/Harish-Chandra, S 6.10. (See image below).

E.g. the integral Heisenberg group $H(\mathbb{Z})$ is cocompact in $H(\mathbb{R})$.

If the OP does not study the full arithmetic unipotent $U(\mathbb{Z})$, but restricts to a subgroup $G \subset U(\mathbb{Z})$, then the answer to the above question is No unless $G$ is finite index in $U(\mathbb{Z})$. Indeed it's evident that discrete subgroups $L'$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ are cocompact in $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $[L':\mathbb{Z}^n]<+\infty$.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear to me that this is the intended question. But the question was rewritten so many times (and will be probably rewritten again) that it's hard to tell.